# Is it possible to load JavaScript file in a WebWorker?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I have a WebWorker which I start with

> new Worker("worker.js");

in this worker I try to load a needed JavaScript file without success via

```
self.importScripts("NeededJs.js");
const m = new NeededJs();
```

How can I solve this issue and include the needed JavaScript File in my WebWorker ?

Edit:

I get the error msg :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: NeededJs is not defined

Thanks

This is the File I need to include 
[File I need to Inlcude](https://github.com/MaiaVictor/WebMonkeys/blob/master/src/WebMonkeys.js)

Comment: Define "without success".  Do you mean you get an exception?  What is the exception?  Do you mean you get no error but something else doesn't work?  Please provide more details.

Comment: Just to be sure... The "NeededJs.js" file contains a "global" available class called `NeededJs`? If not, does it include someting like `this.NeededJs = NeededClass`?

Comment: please have a look at the link i posted.

Comment: Just to state the obvious - `NeededJs` isnt defined in your file. So the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: NeededJs is not defined` is correct.

Comment: ok yes, but can you explain when i include the file via <script src="..."> I can access the NeededJs() class normally ? And how can i access the functions in my WebWorker? Thanks

Comment: Do you mean `WebMonkeys` or are you *really* trying to use `NeededJs`?

Comment: No srry I mean WebMonkeys ...

Comment: Your question doesn't match exactly with what you're trying to do. You're trying to load a Node.js module from a Worker. To do that you would need to look into some library like browserify or similar. What I'd do instead is to download your own copy of the library, get rid of the load function and other stuff, and just leave the WebMonkeys constructor. Then just load your trimmed library from your worker. I tested it and I can guarantee you it works (btw, you need to enable OffscreenCanvas in your browser if it's disabled).

Comment: Thanks alot Diego Pino !

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is possible. You should note its a global function so remove the `self.`

from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

> Worker threads have access to a global function, importScripts(), which lets them import scripts. It accepts zero or more URIs as parameters to resources to import; all of the following examples are valid:

and

> Note: Scripts may be downloaded in any order, but will be executed in the order in which you pass the filenames into importScripts() . This is done synchronously; importScripts() does not return until all the scripts have been loaded and executed.

Also, as you are using the module pattern for your imported file you need to pass an option to specify that:

from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/Worker

```
new Worker("worker.js", {type:"module"});
```

Comment: Didn't work I have to say I load the worker as Blob.

Comment: @Zca89 I think thats probably important information for your question. Dont you?